# How to place a fixed div on owl carousel and make it responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to create a multiple items carousel with a fixed element (a div with a blurb) inside the carousel (on the right, but it doesn't matter, it could be even on the left, at the very center or somewhere, to cover one of the carousel items).
I will upload a picture in other to give you the idea:

[image]

I'm building it with owl carousel as a framework. My biggest problem so far it's that it isn't responsive at all. Whenever I change the screen size, the fixed div (that I put right on the carousel canvas but inside the whole carousel div) will only slightly change, but it won't follow the exact size of each item.

jsFiddle:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   nav: true,
   navText: [
   "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
   "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
   ],
   autoplay: true,
   autoplayHoverPause: true,
   responsive: {
    0: {
     items: 3
    },
    600: {
     items: 3
    },
    1000: {
     items: 3
    }
   }
  });
```

```css
.carousel-wrap {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5%;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
 }

 /* fix blank or flashing items on carousel */
 .owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100; 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 }

 /* end fix */
 .owl-nav > div {
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cdcbcd;
 }

 .owl-nav i {
  font-size: 52px;
 }

 .owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: -30px;
 }

 .owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: -30px;
 }

 .covercarousel {
  float: left;
  width: 23.33%;
 }
 .covercarousel img {
  max-width: 100%
 }
 .owl-carousel {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Carousel</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="carouselwhole">
  <div class="carousel-wrap">

   <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="covercarousel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

It seems perfect at 1280px of width (screen)

[image]

I just need to find a way to make it responsive at any size.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a working example snippet/jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, I'm gonna add it now